# Does a Divine Soul Sorcerer's alignment affect their choice of Divine Magic affinity?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer, alignment, divine

The [Divine Soul Sorcerous Origin](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#DivineSoul) from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (page 50) has the class feature Divine Magic at level 1. It allows you to pick a "free" extra spell based on having an "affinity" with the source of your divine power.

> In addition, choose an affinity for the source of your divine power: good, evil, law, chaos, or neutrality. You learn an additional spell based on that affinity [...]

This choice also affects later class features, such as Otherworldly Wings (the level 14 subclass feature):

> The affinity you chose for your Divine Magic feature determines the appearance of the spectral wings: eagle wings for good or law, bat wings for evil or chaos, and dragonfly wings for neutrality.

**Does your character's alignment have any influence over your choice?** Can a Chaotic Evil sorcerer choose Law, or can a Lawful Good sorcerer choose Neutrality, etc.?

I'm inclined to assume that they are unrelated given that it doesn't explicitly say that it is restricted by your alignment, but the fact that it uses the terms good, evil, law, chaos, makes me doubt myself. I can also see this terminology encouraging a DM to say that it *does* influence your choice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### The affinity for the source of your divine power is not tied to your character's alignment

The relevant part of the [Divine Soul sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#DivineSoul)'s [Divine Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#DivineMagic-745) subclass feature simply says (XGtE, p. 50):

> In addition, choose an affinity for the source of your divine power: good, evil, law, chaos, or neutrality. You learn an additional spell based on that affinity, as shown below. [...]

As you can see, it doesn't restrict your choice of affinity in any way; the very fact that it tells you to choose an affinity indicates that it's not restricted to your own alignment.

Furthermore, the description of the [Divine Soul](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#DivineSoul) sorcerous origin itself doesn't indicate that the divine source you're connected to has to match your own alignment:

> Sometimes the spark of magic that fuels a sorcerer comes from a divine source that glimmers within the soul. Having such a blessed soul is a sign that your innate magic might come from a distant but powerful familial connection to a divine being. Perhaps your ancestor was an angel, transformed into a mortal and sent to fight in a god’s name. Or your birth might align with an ancient prophecy, marking you as a servant of the gods or a chosen vessel of divine magic.

As you can see, there are a variety of ways your powers could be connected to a divine source; you could be descended from one, or you could simply be "marked" as a servant of the gods. Given this indirect connection, and the lack of rules governing the matter, you can pretty easily come up with a justification for why your own alignment might be different from your affinity.

---

Jeremy Crawford, rules designer for 5e, reiterated this interpretation in an [unofficial tweet from November 2017](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/928810291688652800):

> *Q: The Divine Soul chooses an alignment and matching spell at Lv. 1, Must it be the same as character alignment, of can you choose any?*
>
> **The Divine Magic feature doesn't require you to choose your own alignment for the affinity of your divine power.**

This matches what the rules say (and don't say): You can pick any of the five options for the affinity for the source of your divine power, regardless of your character's alignment.

Comment: I'd further note that D&D is full of stories about characters and creatures with natural affinity for a certain alignment turning against that influence, whether that be heroic tieflings rising above the infernal influence in their blood or fallen angels becoming villains. It's perfectly consistent for a sorcerer to be in conflict with their ancestral heritage.

Comment: This is counter-intuitive to me, so thanks for the clarification.